# Does "failed databus stress test" mean bad RAM stick or motherboard?

Tags: memory

I have encountered an error when running a memory test. Does a failed "Databus stress test" mean a problem with the RAM stick, or with the motherboard/chipset?  Or could it be either?

(i.e: is the data bus it's refering to in the RAM stick, or on the motherboard)

Note: I am using the Dell Diagnostics Utility (on a bootable partition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that a "Data Bus Stress Test" in this case tested the RAM stick's bus. The "Data Bus Stress Test" failure/error indicated a problem with one of the RAM sticks.

After experimenting, I found that removing one of the memory sticks solved the problem (eliminated the error). So it was a problem with the RAM stick.